# Regular expression parsing ip address from a string

Tags: xml, regex

How can I parse a string using regular expression. I will get this string below. (I only need the regular expression.)

Lets called this string access_indicator and IP address combined

```
RCHLMI55---01CAB101A-71.151.193.98
TROZMIYZ---01CAB101A-71.151.193.54
RCHLMI59---01CAB101A-71.151.193.99
TROAMIAM---01CAB101A-71.151.193.101
Future_7330
```

I need to parse only IP addresses. I tried using `\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b` to get the IP address but I got an error

```
ERROR - sbc.cms.xml.XMLException: <input> element #1's ip_addr <field> element(#20) must have at least one capturing group in the regular expression of its edit attribute.
```

Also, I need to get the access indicator and parse it as it is below, sometimes it won't have an IP address when it doesn't have an IP address I can keep the whole access indicator string:

```
RCHLMI55---01CAB101A
TROZMIYZ---01CAB101A
RCHLMI59---01CAB101A
TROAMIAM---01CAB101A
Future_7330
```

@bytebender posting the rest of the code below, we are using XML to parse it

```
<field name="ip_addr" count="16" delimiter="{_csv_}" edit="re=\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b" allow-blank="yes" />
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? I think the error is occurring where you are actually calling the regex code.

Comment: @bytebender post it above

Comment: If you're using xml, why did you tagged `Javascript` and not `XML` ?

Comment: I only wanted the regular expression and the regular expression its javascript.

Comment: adding parenthesis fixed it `(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)` for the ip address

Comment: I still need help parsing the access indicator

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "everything after the last dash" would work:

```
[^-]+$
```